# What is the current state of Casper?

Tags: proof-of-stake

I've been reading a bit about Casper, but I couldn't find anything recent nor any technical details about it.

I know the protocol is not finished but is there any information about it? I mean more than just a high level overview as one can read in the "Introducing Casper" post on the blog

Also I was wondering if they were still working on Slasher or if it had been completely forsaken?

Answer (score 4):

Ethnews also had [a recent article about it](https://www.ethnews.com/proof-of-stake-vitalik-buterin-shares-casper-contract-code).  According to them, a profitable POS validator will need a minimum of 1000 to 4000eth just to cover their gas cost.  At $200/eth that's $200k $800k invested and locked up just to participate.  The irony is that POS was suppose to improve democratization but instead it ensures only the very wealthy will be able to participate.  How funny, better start saving now!

Answer (score 2):

Vitalik shared some preliminary Casper code with the world last month (at the time of writing, last month was April 2017), which can be found on GitHub:

https://github.com/ethereum/research/blob/master/casper4/simple_casper.v.py

(I've not kept up to date with Vlad's implementation.)

Shortly before this (March 2017), Vitalik released a blog post detailing how slashing conditions might (will?) work:

[Medium: Minimal Slashing Conditions](https://medium.com/@VitalikButerin/minimal-slashing-conditions-20f0b500fc6c)